# Capture multi-line result with mysql_fetch_array() function

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, json

I have a php function that captures coordinates of a place from mySQL data base and returns the result:

```
public function getCoordinatesByName($name) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places WHERE name = '$name'") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $result;
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This function is used in index.php to capture the result and send it via JSON to an Android device:

```
$place = $db->getCoordinatesByName($name);
if ($place != false) {
    // user found
    // echo json with success = 1

    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["place"]["H"] = $place["H"];
    $response["place"]["V"] = $place["V"];
    $response["place"]["placeid"] = $place["placeid"];
    $response["place"]["name"] = $place["name"];
    $response["place"]["type"] = $place["type"];
    $response["place"]["note"] = $place["note"];
    $response["place"]["discription"] = $place["discription"];
    //$response["place"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
    //$response["place"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Now that I want to send all of the the coordinates of all the places at oncen I created a function called getCoordinates:

```
 public function getCoordinates($name) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM places") or die(mysql_error());
        // check for result 
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            return $result;
        } else {
            // user not found
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Then I used it in index.php this way :

```
 $place = $db->getCoordinates($name);
 if ($place != false) {
     for ($i = 1;$i = count($place); $i++ ) {
         // user found
         // echo json with success = 1
         $response[$i]["success"] = 1;
         $response[$i]["place"]["H"] = $place[$i]["H"];
         $response[$i]["place"]["V"] = $place[$i]["V"];
         $response[$i]["place"]["placeid"] = $place[$i]["placeid"];
         $response[$i]["place"]["name"] = $place[$i]["name"];
         $response[$i]["place"]["type"] = $place[$i]["type"];
         $response[$i]["place"]["note"] = $place[$i]["note"];
         //$response["place"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
         //$response["place"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
     }
     echo json_encode($response);
 }
```

I think something is not right, because I always get errors when I run the application from an Android device

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_fetch_array()` (and its cousins `_assoc` and `_object`) return a single **ROW** of data. They do not fetch the entire query result. You need to build an array of rows, then return that:

```
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $data[] = $row;
}
return $data;
```

Then you'll get your array that you can iterate over.